# VB.Net Extract numbers from string function

Tags: vb.net, function, numbers, extract

My request is one that can extract a number somewhat by a search.

Example:
`animalsOwned|4` would return an containing "4"

`animals|3|2|1|3` would return an array containing "3", "2", "1", "3"

This would make it easier for me during a file stream reader.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regular expression. It's a powerful tool for simple text parsing.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Namespace Demo
    Class Program
        Shared Function Main(ByVal args As String()) As Integer
            Dim array As Integer() = ExtractIntegers("animals|3|2|1|3")
            For Each i In array
                Console.WriteLine(i)
            Next
            Return 0
        End Function
        Shared Function ExtractIntegers(ByVal input As String) As Integer()
            Dim pattern As String = "animals(\|(?<number>[0-9]+))*"
            Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
            Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
            If match.Success Then
                For Each capture As Capture In match.Groups("number").Captures
                    list.Add(Integer.Parse(capture.Value))
                Next
            End If
            Return list.ToArray()
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's along the lines of what I wanted :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim astring = "ABCDE|1|2|3|4"

Dim numbers = (From s In astring
               Where Char.IsDigit(s)
               Select Int32.Parse(s)).ToArray()
```

This LINQ statement should help. It simply checks each character in a string to see if it's a digit. Note that this only applies to single digit numbers. It becomes a bit more complicated if you want "ABC123" to return 123 vs. 1, 2, 3 array.

Comment: Right that's along the lines I'm looking for, but what if the string contains:
"ABCDE|2 ABC|2|2|4" and I want to retrieve "2" by searching "ABCDE" ?

Comment: @Alex I think I understand what you are saying. It appears in your comment that you have a "space" between two strings (ABCDE|2 and ABC|2|2|4). In that case, you could simply split the string into two string arrays using the .Split method. Then use the approach I suggested above.

Comment: Without knowing exactly how your file is standardized, there could be all kinds of weird solutions. Regex may be in order if you have something very convoluted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! With a little bit of tweeking the regex answer was correct!

Comment: You can use the .join method at the end of the array to return a full string if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't programmed VB for awhile but I'll give you some pseudo code:
First, loop through each line of file. Call this variable Line.
Then, take the index of what you're searching for: like Line.indexOf("animalsOwned")
If it returns -1 it isn't there; continue.
Once you find it, add the Index variable to the length of the search string and 1. (Index=Index+1+Len(searchString))
Then, take a substring starting there, and end at the end of the line.
Explode the substring by | characters, then add each into an array.
Return the array.

Sorry that I can't give you much help, but I'm working on an important PHP website right now ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `variable.Split("|")` and then assign each piece to an array level.

You can do a count on string and with a while or for loop, you can assign the splited sections to array levels. Then you can do a `IsNumeric()` check for each array level.