# how to read only numbers from text file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, integer

Hello people as the topic show I want to do in VB.net a script that gets only the numbers from a *.txt file

EXAMPLE:

text file:
asd4lkj5fdl
jklj235

the result:
45235

I have done a research in Google and come up with nothing, I did saw a answer here but only in C
I know that in theory it needs to be like this:
Read every char loop ask if it is an integer add it to a new string if not continue to next char do this till the end of the stream

Thanks for the one how helps !

Comment: How could your Google search come up with nothing? If I search "vb.net extract numbers from text" or similar I find many results, including this [SO one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064468/vb-net-extract-numbers-from-string-function)

Comment: Sorry but I used other sentences on my search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read File into a String
2. Loop through each char checking if numeric.

   ```
   Dim strTextFromFile As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\filename.txt")

   Dim strResults As String = String.Empty

   For Each c As Char In strTextFromFile

       If IsNumeric(c) Then

           strResults += c

       End If

   Next

   MsgBox(strResults)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try regular expressions, code to read text from file is no included

```
Dim rgx As New Regex("[^\d]")
Dim result as String = rgx.Replace("asd4lkj5fdl jklj235", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim contents As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\\temp\\text.txt")
    Dim digits As New String(contents.Where(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
    MessageBox.Show(digits)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it two !
but when I used your code it told me that the output is a prompt and that I cant convert to string....

Comment: Try now, i mistakenly converted string to char array

Comment: Still not working the contents wasn't the problem the problem is when I want to put the digits in MsgBox is when i get the message about the prompt that cant convert into string

Comment: Sorry, it was because digits was not string because of char array but now this code will work :) I tested.